# Floating Action Button Bottom-Margin doesn't work

Tags: android, margin, floating-action-button

I tried to implement a Floating Button on the bottom-right of the screen, but the bottom-margin doesn't work for some reason :/ I tried to change the margin size only on the Bottom but it didn't work.

Layout Files:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**app_bar_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="de.js_labs.gaminggroups.MainActivity"
android:id="@+id/appBarMainRl">

<include
layout="@layout/some_content" // Changed by LayoutInflater in Java ...
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**some_content.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
app:useCompatPadding="true"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingTop="50dp"
android:id="@+id/contentMyGroupsRl"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_action_addgroup"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Screenshot:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/COpgF.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, try to remove this line

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

from `FloatingActionButton`

Second Step, move `FloatingActionButton` from Relative layout to `CoordinatorLayout` itself, as a **direct child**.

Should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="de.js_labs.gaminggroups.MainActivity"
android:id="@+id/appBarMainRl">

<include
layout="@layout/some_content" // Changed by LayoutInflater in Java ...
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_action_addgroup"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you :) I kown that this works but is it possible to put the floating-button in the content layout file? Or should I just make it invisible when I'm changing the content layout?

Comment: @Janik174 When you change the layout, you can use fab.hide() and fab.show() methods to change visibility with animation.

Answer (score 7):

Try adding the `app:useCompatPadding="true"` in the FloatingActionButton tag as shown below:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:scaleType="center"
        app:fabSize="mini"
        app:useCompatPadding="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="de.js_labs.gaminggroups.MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/appBarMainRl">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_action_addgroup"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: This code works, but is it possible to put the floating-button in the content layout file?

Comment: yes try add **<include
layout="@layout/some_content" // Changed by LayoutInflater in Java ...
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />** and in some layout remove this from fab **android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"** and see if works

Comment: rememenber to keep some layout like you have in question only remove **android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"** @Janik174